# StepFunctions Pass name of state to next state even in case of failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I know I can create a key-value pair and add it to ResultSelector however this only occurs if the state executes successfully.  Is there a way to pass custom informatino in this way regardless of whether the state succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

No, ResultSelector is not available in Catch fields. However, [ResultPath is supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-error-handling.html#error-handling-fallback-states) which will allow you to pass on the input as well as the errors to the Fallback State. If you then use a Pass state for Fallback, [you can augment the payload using Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) (which behaves similarly to ResultSelector).